# Non-transparent image within a semi-transparent div

Tags: jquery, css

**CSS**

```
.popup {
    z-index: 10000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); 
    -moz-opacity: .40;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="popup" style="display: none; overflow: auto;">
    <img  src="~/image.png" /> <!--it also becomes transparent. -->
</div>
```

I would like not to make the image transparent. Any help?

Comment: Any element that is inside another element with opacity less than 1, can not be displayed with opacity grater than it's parent element.

Comment: Every child element inherits properties from parent element. so its not possible until unless you try some other approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting transparency for `background-color` instead of `opacity` for element as below

`background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5); //0.5 is the transparency you are setting for color`

for more info see this **[Article](http://www.css3.info/opacity_rgba_and_compromise/)**